# Show $\gcd$ are equivalent

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let $x, y, z$ be integers. Show that if $\gcd(x, y) = 1$, then $\gcd(x, yz) = 1$ or $z$.

I have no clue how to prove this, I know it true for a fact.

How can I approach it?

Comment: Probably you mean $z$ to be a prime number, no? In that case, it's true but somehow trivial.

Comment: It feels like you're missing something, like perhaps the requirement that $\gcd(x, z) = 1$ as well.

Comment: That's false without additional assumptions. Take for example any two distinct primes $p,q$ and let $x=p^2,y=q,z=p q$.

Answer (score 4):

$\gcd(6,5)=1$, but $\gcd(6,5 \cdot 21)=3$.